# How to handle SEH exception on a global level

Tags: c++, seh

I wanted to catch SEH exception globally i.e. if a SEH exception occurs in a thread of an object of ClassB called in ClassA, is it possible to catch the SEH exception in Main (ClassA instance is called in Main)?

I have been using SetUnhandledExceptionFilter in Main to catch these SEH exceptions but I failed to catch for this case particularly. Since there are multiple classes and program is multi-threaded, I am looking for options to catch it on a global level. (Note: The compiler has been set to /EHa flag.)

```
  MyUnhandledExceptionFilter(Exception ptr){

     //Handle SEH exception 
  }


    ClassA
    {
     //Some stuff ...
     ClassB objB.DoSomething();
    }


    ClassB{

      DoSomething(){
      CreateThread(Threadfunc)
      };

      ThreadFunc(){
         //SEH exception occurs;
      }
    }



   int main(){
    SetUnhandledExceptionFilter(MyUnhandledExceptionFilter);
    try
   {
     ClassA objA::run();

    }
   catch(exception ex){
      //Log here 
    }
  }
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21702640/seh-stackoverflow-exception-is-it-real-not-possible-to-catch

Comment: Looks a different question to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Vectored Exception Handling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/vectored-exception-handling):

> Vectored exception handlers are an extension to structured exception handling. **An application can register a function to watch or handle all exceptions for the application.** Vectored handlers are not frame-based, therefore, you can add a handler that will be called regardless of where you are in a call frame. Vectored handlers are called in the order that they were added, after the debugger gets a first chance notification, but before the system begins unwinding the stack.

For example:

```
#include <windows.h>

LONG WINAPI MyVectoredExceptionHandler(PEXCEPTION_POINTERS ExceptionInfo)
{
    // Log here ...

    return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH; // or EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION
}

class ClassB
{
public:
    void DoSomething() {
        HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, &ThreadFunc, NULL, 0, NULL);
        if (hThread) CloseHandle(hThread);
    }

    static DWORD WINAPI ThreadFunc(LPVOID) {
        //SEH exception occurs
    }
};

class ClassA
{
public:
    ClassB objB;

    void run() {
        // Some stuff ...
        objB.DoSomething();
    }
};

int main(){
    AddVectoredExceptionHandler(0, &MyVectoredExceptionHandler);
    ClassA objA;
    objA.run();
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! When you wrote " handle all exceptions " does this mean it handles C++ exceptions as well or it's limited to SEHs?

Comment: It is limited to just SEH, however most C++ compilers for Windows use SEH for their C++ exception handling (though that is a implementation detail and not a requirement).  C++ does not have a concept of a global exception handler across thread boundaries, a thrown C++ exception can only be caught in the throwing thread. However, a thread can capture a C++ exception using `std::current_exception()` and re-throw it in another thread using `std:::rethrow_exception()`.

Comment: Microsoft's documentation says it can catch all exceptions, is that true? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/vectored-exception-handling

Comment: @Batmon AFAIK, VEH handlers are registered globally but then called in the context of whatever thread throws an SEH exception (ie, only 1 thread at a time can invoke VEH handlers as access to the VEH list is serialized behind a thread-safe lock). SEH itself is handled per-thread only, since SEH handlers are tied to the throwing thread's call stack, whereas VEH handlers are not. Have a look at [Under the Hood: New Vectored Exception Handling in Windows XP](https://bytepointer.com/resources/pietrek_vectored_exception_handling.htm) for details.